# Question regarding Ehresmann connection

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Assume we have a fiber bundle $F\to E\stackrel \pi\to B$.

In the wikipedia article it is stated that $E$ the vertical bundle $V=\ker d\pi$ consisting of vectors along the fibers is canonically defined while the horizontal bundle of vectors along the base is not.
Specifying a horizintal subspace of $TE$ is then called an Ehresmann connection on $E$.

But isn't $\pi^* TB$ a canonical subbundle of $TE$ which consists of vectors along $B$?

Answer (score 2):

No!  There is no reason why $\pi^*TB$ is a subbundle of $TE$ -- this is precisely why you need a connexion.

Recall $\pi^*TB$ is actually constructed as $E\times_B TB$:
$$
\pi^*TB=\{(e,(p,v))\in E\times TB\mid \pi(e)=\operatorname{proj}_{TB\to B}(p,v)=p\}
$$
where $\operatorname{proj}_{TB\to B}$ is the usual projection $TB\to B$.

Comment: Then why is it claimed differently here? http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Tangent_bundles_of_bundles_(Ex)

Comment: A connexion $\nabla$ is precisely a choice of splitting $TE=H\oplus V$ with $H\cong \pi^*TB$.  You don't have a canonical choice of $H$.

Comment: So independently of the connection, there always is an isomorphism $H\to \pi^* TB$? Specifying such an isomorphism does then define a unique connection?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the pullback, $\pi^*B=\{(x,y,v):y\in\pi^{-1}(x), v\in T_xB\}$  therefore it is not a subbundle of $TE$.

Comment: Hm, when I googled "tangent bundle of fiber bundle" i found this site: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Tangent_bundles_of_bundles_(Ex), where something else was claimed (ex1). Could you please take a look at it?