# Tangent bundle of a fiber bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

This is a follow up to my question [about Ehresmann connections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252163/question-regarding-ehresmann-connection).

Let $F\to E\stackrel p \to B$ be a fiber bundle. Then $V:=\ker dp \subset TE$ is a subbundle. Furthermore, $i^*TE = V$. A connection is nothing else than defining a splitting $TE = H \oplus V$.

Is it true that independently of the connection, there always is an isomorphism $p^* TB \to H$? If yes, how is it defined?

Comment: You don't have $H$ without a connexion.

Comment: What you do have is an isomorphism $TE/V\cong p^*TB$

Comment: @Danu This is what I suspected. Is the isomorphism the map $dp$?

Comment: It is the map induced by $dp$, yes.